# How do I write a unit test in jest for a class function in the database layer of my javascript web application?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using jest to write unit tests for my Express app. I am new with testing as well as using jest, so I am having a difficult time writing a unit test for my class functions that represent my database layer of my application. When I run the test, the program tries to make a call to the db, but is unable to do so, falling to the catch block. Where did I go wrong? Thank you.

// summary.ts

```
import db from '../db/index';
import { generateError } from '../lib/generateError';

const SummaryModel = class {
  static async findAll() {
    const text = `SELECT * FROM public.summary`;
    let result : any = {};
    try {
      result = await db.query(text);
    } catch(e) {
      if (e) {
        throw generateError(500, 'could not query db');
      }
    }
    const summaries = {
      record: result.rows,
      count: result.rowCount
    }
    return summaries;
  }
}
export default SummaryModel;
```

// summary.test.js

```
const SummaryModel = require('../../../src/models/summary');
jest.mock('../../../src/models/summary');

test('should return an object with an array and number', async done => {
  const summaries = await SummaryModel.default.findAll();
  expect(typeof summaries.record).toBe('array');
  expect(typeof summaries.count).toBe('number');
  done();
});
```

// summary.test.js **UPDATED**

```
const SummaryModel = require('../../../src/models/summary');
jest.mock('../../../src/models/summary');

test('should return an object with an array and number', async done => {
  const SummaryModel = {
    default: {
      findAll: jest.fn()
    },
  }
  const resp = {
    record: [{},{}],
    count: 2,
  }
  SummaryModel.default.findAll.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  const summaries = await SummaryModel.default.findAll();
  expect(summaries.record.length).toBe(2);
  expect(summaries.count).toBe(2);
  expect(typeof summaries.record).toBe('object');
  expect(typeof summaries.count).toBe('number');
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to mock the values which would be normally returned by your method. To do so, you can use the function `mockResolvedValue` to bypass the call to the DB and return the test data you want everytime `findAll` is invoked.
For instance you could have something like:

```
SummaryModel.default.findAll.mockResolvedValue({
  record: [{}, {}], // return some test data here
  count: 2,
}
```

Check Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules) on how to mock modules.

Comment: Thank you. It is very much appreciated. I've updated my question with working code.